# Is there a way to check if a function is currently running in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a document that may give the user the ability to run the same function more than once. Is there a way to check if the function is currently running before I can reactivate it again?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set an external flag.

```
var functionIsRunning = false;

function myFunction() {
    if (!functionIsRunning) {
        functionIsRunning = true;
        //do stuff
        functionIsRunning = false;
    }
}
```

The same principle applies to jQuery functions.

Answer (score 8):

That's very easy. The function is not running.

Javascript is strictly single threaded. If the browser is responding to any user events, there is no function currently running.

Comment: while this is true, you might want to only queue the invocations after the previous code has finished running. esp. if using timers http://jsfiddle.net/gryzzly/ZGVan/ in the first case, without prevention animations will stack up (I know about jQuery's helper "stop" function and that jQuery generally allows you to interact with animations, it's only an example of timers being involved).

Comment: @gryzzly: That's something completely different. If you are waiting for an animation to end, you are not checking if a function is currently running, you are waiting for code running in a timer to reach a specific state.

Answer (score 1):

If your calling alot of functions there are plenty of utilities to help you manage this check out Promise

http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag. Something like this:

```
(function () {

    // your application within a closure to not pollute global scope
    var handlerRunning = false;
    // the function that will be called and shouldn't be running twice
    var handler = function () {
        if (handlerRunning) return;
        handlerRunning = true;
        // do stuff here
        // when you're done, set handlerRunning to false
        handlerRunning = false;
    }

    // assign your code to event handler for example
    document.getElementById('awesome-button').addEventListener('click', handler, false);

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

No off the top of my head, but you could use a variable to set whether a function being executed. something like :

```
function MyWrapper() {    
    this.running = false;
    this.run = function() {
        if (this.running==false) {
            this.running = true;
            // do something
            this.running = false;
            return true;
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`jQuery.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

> If a single Deferred is passed to `jQuery.when`, its Promise object (a subset of the Deferred methods) is returned by the method. Additional methods of the Promise object can be called to attach callbacks, such as [`deferred.then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/). When the Deferred is resolved or rejected, usually by the code that created the Deferred originally, the appropriate callbacks will be called. For example, the jqXHR object returned by `jQuery.ajax()` is a Promise and can be used this way:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "test.aspx" ) ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
   alert( jqXHR.status ); // Alerts 200
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A late reply, but still I wanted to register my answer here.
I encountered a similar issue where I've a background server check function with `setInterval` embedded in it. But, there are also a lot of possibilities in my code to trigger the same function on some other criteria. So, to make sure I'm not recalling it, I simply used local storage to ensure the function is not called again and again.

This function is in my HTML file,

```
function serverCheck(value){
   localStorage.setItem("isFunctionRunning",1); 
   setInterval(checkServerStatus, value);
}
```

The below snippet is in my another JS file,

```
function xyz(){
   //someCode
   var checkFunction = localStorage.getItem("isFunctionRunning");
   if(checkFunction != 1){
      serverCheck(frequency);
   }
}
```